# How can disable an option select if its text is equal to another text in a div?

Tags: jquery

My html is

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle">My text</div>
<div class="dropdown-toggle">Not my text</div>
<div class="dropdown-toggle">My text</div>

<select>
  <option>My text</option>
  <option>My text</option>
  <option>Not my text></option>
</select>
```

The jQuery that might work

```
if($("option").text() == $(".dropdown-toggle").text()) {

}
```

The result that i am looking to achieve is:

```
<select>
  <option disable="disabled">My text</option>
  <option disable="disabled">My text</option>
  <option>Not my text></option>
</select>
```

What I cannot figure out is how to target the option which has the same text as per the div text with a specific class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").each(function(){
  var ddrtext=$(this).text();
  $('option').filter(function(){
    return ddrtext==$(this).text();
  }).attr('disabled','disabled')
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s1dyzq9m/)**

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("option").each(function(idx){
if($(this).text() == $(".dropdown-toggle").eq(idx).text()) {
   $(this).prop("disabled",true);
}
});
```